filesystem is mounted as read-only, if mount command called from python
I have custom python software, which monitors udev and if usb disk is pluged in, it mounts it by calling os.system(f'mount {device.device_node} /some/path/usb'). Problem is, that usb disk is mounted as read only with no obvious reason.
If I call exactly the same command from command line, it works as fine, mounts filesystem as read-write. Originally, I have run my python software as systemd service, but i have tried run it from command line with no effect. I also tried explicitly add -o rw or --rw options, but with no effect either. I have tried to add some waiting time between usb disk detection and mount command call, but still no effect. Do you have any idea, whats wrong here?

What's the file system? what does /proc/$$/mountinfo show as mount options? Is it really mounted read-only or is it mounted read only vs the other user?

@AnyaShenanigans, I says 54 50 8:1 / /my/path/usb rw,relatime shared:165 - vfat /dev/sda1 ro,sync,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro when mounted from python and 54 50 8:1 / /my/path/usb rw,relatime shared:165 - vfat /dev/sda1 rw,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro when mounted manually

I have found solution: I have just added -o errors=continue and it did the trick

This is not a great choice - it indicates that the file system is corrupt in some way. You should use the output from dmesg to see why it's changing to read-only - it might be pending writes, which means you might be losing data.

Use the mount command from the cli to find the mounted location and see if additional options are passed to the mount command which you need to add (like nfs version as an example).

How can I check additional options passed when i use mount command from CLI? Where are these came from?
